# Enable select on checkbox checked inside for loop

Tags: javascript, angular

I am working on a requirement wherein I need to associate priorities to every item.

The Item is the Checkbox element.
Checking an item should enable the Select underneath it ONLY. This select has numbers in it to assign the priority.

Like this -

[image]

The Condition is ONLY that select should get enabled for which the checkbox is checked.

Below is the code which I have come up with, so that these controls can be created dynamically.

```
<div class="panel-body">
  <div *ngFor="let wt of Wts; let i=index">
    <input type="checkbox" [(ngModel)]="wt.ischecked" name="rdWt" (change)="changeforSelectedWt(wt)" />{{wt.Name}}
    <br/>
    <u>Current Priority</u> : {{currentPriority}}
    <select class="form-control" (change)="priorityChanged(selectedPriority)" style="width:200px">
      <option value="0">Select New Priority</option>
      <option *ngFor="let wt of Wts; let priority=index">
        {{priority + 1}}
      </option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
```

The change event of the checkbox is as below

```
changeforSelectedWt(data) {
  //debugger;
  console.log('event data is---', data);
  this.spinner.show();
  this.Wts.forEach(x => {
    // debugger;
    if (x.ischecked == true) {
      debugger;
      console.log(x);
    }
    this.spinner.hide();
  });
}
```

How can i make sure that ONLY when i check any checkbox, the Select underneath it should get enable rest remain disable.
I also need the checkbox value and value in select.

Is this really feasible with this approach or do i need to create Individual control in the html.